# Apache conf changes when migrating django project from mod_python to mod_wsgi

Tags: apache-2.2, django, mod-wsgi, mod-python

Not sure if this is the right place to ask this question, but I'm migrating a django project from mod_python to mod_wsgi and I want to make sure I have my apache configuration correct. The old configuration looks like this:

```
DocumentRoot /srv/www/PROJECT/
    <location "/">
            Options +FollowSymLinks
            allow from all
            SetHandler python-program
            PythonHandler django.core.handlers.modpython
            SetEnv DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE PROJECT.settings
            PythonPath "['/srv/www/PROJECT'] + sys.path"
            PythonDebug On                
            PythonInterpreter PROJECT
    </location>
    <location "/site_media/">
            Options +FollowSymLinks
            SetHandler None
    </location>
    <location "/admin_media/">
            Options +FollowSymLinks
            SetHandler None
    </location>

<Location "/server-status">
    SetHandler server-status
    Allow from .test.org localhost 127.0.0.1
</Location>
```

Reading the documentation, it seems like all I have to do is:

```
    WSGIDaemonProcess PROJECT processes=2 threads=15 display-name=%{GROUP}
    WSGIProcessGroup PROJECT
    WSGIScriptAlias /PROJECT /srv/www/django.wsgi

    <Directory /srv/www/PROJECT/ >
            Order allow,deny
            Allow from all
    </Directory>

    Alias /site_media "/srv/www/site_media/"
    Alias /admin_media "/srv/www/admin_media/"
```

With django.wsgi containing:

```
 import os,sys
 sys.path.append('/srv/www/PROJECT')
 os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'settings'

 import django.core.handlers.wsgi
 application = django.core.handlers.wsgi.WSGIHandler()
```

Do these look like the appropriate changes? I am not too familiar with mod_python (I didn't set this site up- it's just my job now to migrate it :( ) so I'm not sure on the conversion. Any other advice would be much appreciated.

Comment: Why don't you try the configuration which documentation for mod_wsgi says to use and see if it works? Just make sure you disable mod_python from same Apache so it doesn't cause issues.

Comment: It seems to half work- I'll post updated results if I get it working.